# Assign a date to specific text in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, forex

I have a data frame in R as follows called `Ident`.

```
        Date coredata.Ident.
1  2017-09-01            <NA>
2  2017-09-03            <NA>
3  2017-09-04            <NA>
4  2017-09-05               0
5  2017-09-06               0
6  2017-09-07               0
7  2017-09-08               0
8  2017-09-10               0
9  2017-09-11            Doji
10 2017-09-12            <NA>
11 2017-09-13               0
12 2017-09-14  Bull.Engulfing
13 2017-09-15               0
14 2017-09-17               0
15 2017-09-18  Bear.Engulfing
16 2017-09-19            Doji
17 2017-09-20  Bear.Engulfing
18 2017-09-21  Bull.Engulfing
19 2017-09-22               0
20 2017-09-24               0
21 2017-09-25  Bear.Engulfing
22 2017-09-26               0
23 2017-09-27               0
24 2017-09-28               0
25 2017-09-29               0
```

I would like to assign the next date after that there is a `Bull.Engulfing` to a variable called `DateSelect1` and then the second `Bull.Engulfing` would be assigned to `DateSelect2` etc. So that all of the `Bull.Engulfing` have a date assigned to them.

So in this example, as there is a `Bull.Engulfing` on `2017-09-14` line 12, `DateSelect1` should be `2017-09-15` as it is the next row. Hope this makes sense.

TIA

Comment: Could you include the sample of what you are hoping to see? From the explanation, I am not sure what result you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input in the Note subset the data frame and assign each date in that subset to a variable:

```
dates <- as.Date(subset(DF, coredata.Ident. == "Bull.Engulfing")$Date)
for(i in seq_along(dates)) assign(paste0("DateSelect", i), dates[i])

DateSelect1
## [1] "2017-09-14"
DateSelect2
## [1] "2017-09-21"
```

**Note:**  The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
        Date coredata.Ident.
1  2017-09-01            <NA>
2  2017-09-03            <NA>
3  2017-09-04            <NA>
4  2017-09-05               0
5  2017-09-06               0
6  2017-09-07               0
7  2017-09-08               0
8  2017-09-10               0
9  2017-09-11            Doji
10 2017-09-12            <NA>
11 2017-09-13               0
12 2017-09-14  Bull.Engulfing
13 2017-09-15               0
14 2017-09-17               0
15 2017-09-18  Bear.Engulfing
16 2017-09-19            Doji
17 2017-09-20  Bear.Engulfing
18 2017-09-21  Bull.Engulfing
19 2017-09-22               0
20 2017-09-24               0
21 2017-09-25  Bear.Engulfing
22 2017-09-26               0
23 2017-09-27               0
24 2017-09-28               0
25 2017-09-29               0"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```